# Possible To Add Colour Hue to Scene in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I have a scene set up in threejs with some very basic shapes, and I want to "shift" all colours in the scene to have purple hue to them (almost as if there was a purple opaque screen overlaying on top). I understand that a way to adjust colour/hue settings in a scene all at once is to use post-processing effects, but running through those listed effects I can't work out if any can help me here

Is this effect possible to achieve? Any guidance or link to appropriate resources would be appreciated here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with an instance of `THREE.ShaderPass` and a [ColorCorrectionShader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/shaders/ColorCorrectionShader.js).

You can find such a setup in the official example: [webgl_materials_normalmap](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap)

Comment: ah one thing i've noticed is that my pixel resolution appears to have been downgraded just by adding this ColorCorrectionShader, is this a common issue?

Comment: When using post-processing you can't use the default MSAA which is enabled by passing `antialias: true` to the renderer. However, the resolution should be the same as before. Consider to use an additional shader pass with an FXAA shader. Place it behind the color correction pass in your pass chain.

Comment: ah I wasn't aware of this, if I remove anti-aliasing manually without post processing I get what I referred to as the degraded pixel resolution. Adding in FXAA unfortunately doesn't do much to help, but I will look into how to configure it properly